# Accessing an MTP/WPD device in Visual Basic .NET

Tags: vb.net, dll, mtp, wpd

Are there any libraries available for VB.net which will enable me to easily access a MTP device? I'd like to be able to find out what devices are connected, list the contents of them and copy files to and from them.

Everything I've seen so far (either at Stack Overflow, on the Microsoft site or with a simple Google search) is either in C++, C# or some other language that isn't VB.net. The Microsoft documentation goes completely over my head.

As a result, it's all non-starter unless I plan to learn a new language.

I did find [MTPSharp](http://mtpsharp.sourceforge.net/) which gave me hope. However there is no documentation, it doesn't appear to be fully implemented, my attempts to do certain things return an exception and the author tells me that it's written against an old API I shouldn't use and is unable to help me with the questions I have.

Is there really no hope for someone who wants to use VB.net?

Comment: Why does the Lib have to be in VB?  You use code from compiled C# assemblies all the time - the NET Framework.  The blog code could easily be converted to a class lib.

Comment: surely you could find a code converter

Comment: Turning the blog code into a class lib is beyond my capabilities given that I don't understand C# well enough to know what is going on.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for the hint about the code converter. Didn't realise there was such a thing. Will give it a shot.

Comment: A code converter alone wont work - there are some `unsafe` blocks using pointers which do not have a simple translation to VB.

Answer (score 7):

### A Window Portable Device Class Lib

Note: this is the work of **Christophe Geers** from a series of blogs which can be [found here](https://cgeers.wordpress.com/category/programming/wpd/)

I mainly added a few functions, a VB console test, and converted it to a Class Lib.  I tweaked a few things in the code to streamline it, but they are not worth further mention.

**Documentation:**

***Study*** [Mr Geers' blog](https://cgeers.wordpress.com/category/programming/wpd/).

Visual Studio's IntelliSense will also be valuable in identifying the properties and methods available.

#### Important Notes

**Caveat**

I have very few portable devices (and cant find one), so testing was rather limited.

**Files and Folders**

The term `File` and `Folder` in this context can be misleading.

As the article makes clear, there is a `PortableDeviceObject` type (class) from which both `PortableDeviceFile` and `PortableDeviceFolder` inherit.  `PortableDeviceObject` has a property collection named `Files`, but that collection actually contains `PortableDeviceObject`s.  Any one of the items in that collection may in fact be another folder.

I started to implement a Folders collection as well, then figured out why it is the way it is.  Since a folder can contain sub-folders, it would be more confusing and problematic to link files to subfolders to folders to a PortableDevice.  So, I left it.

**This means each item in the `Files` collection must be tested to see whether it is really a `File` or a `Folder`**.  This would typically be done one of two ways:

```
' using VB operator
If TypeOf item Is PortableDeviceFolder Then
    Console.Beep()
End If

' using NET Type method
If item.GetType Is GetType(PortableDeviceFolder) Then
    Console.Beep()
End If
```

To make things *slightly* simpler and more object oriented, I added an `IsFile` and `IsFolder` function to `PortableDeviceObject` which allows:

```
If item.IsFolder Then
   DisplayFolderContents(dev, CType(item, PortableDeviceFolder))
End If
```

There is also a method which returns an `ItemType` enum value (there is also a static version which may be useful):

```
' using GetItemType
If item.GetItemType = PortableDeviceObject.ItemTypes.File Then
    Console.Beep()
End If
```

### Resources

Mr Geers' [original source](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40603470/WPDTransferToDevice.zip)

[Another C# Project](https://code.google.com/p/nikon-camera-control/source/browse/trunk/PortableDeviceLib/DevicePortablePKeys.cs?r=156) for WPD which may be useful

[MSDN Windows Portable Devices documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388998(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information when you get ready to make mods later.

A VB Console app (just a translation) shows how to use some of the functions.  Study the blog fr details.

The code is long, would largely duplicate Mr Geers' blog, and I am disinclined to post code which is not mine. Besides, C# code would apparently do you little good if you can't compile it to a DLL.  So,  to answer the question posed, *Are there any libraries available for VB.net which will enable me to easily access a MTP device?*:

**Yes.**  The modified source, project files (VS2012), a new VB console test app and Binaries (`PortableDevices.dll`) can be [downloaded from DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8hfctmxsy0j75ft/Windows%20Portable%20Devices.zip?dl=0).  The bin/compile folders includes Builds for AnyCPU/Release and x86/Release

- I *think* you will want to keep the `Interop.*` DLLs located in those folders with the `PortableDevice.DLL`.  For instance, copy them both along with the DLL to your tools directory.  I am not sure why he did it that way.
- To use the new Class Lib in a project, you obviously will need a add a reference to your brand new `PortableDevice.DLL`.

Of course, with the project source files you can load it and recompile to whatever format you desire.  VS compiles C# projects the same way you do in VB.

[image]

*Works on My Machine<sup>TM</sup>*

Again, to be clear, this is not my work.  I mainly compiled it to DLL.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty awesome. Thank you very much! I've given it a go but it throws an unhandled exception when looking at my Galaxy S3. Is there any way I could be really cheeky and ask if you don't mind grabbing my email from my profile so I can send you this message? I promise not to waste too much of your time.

Comment: I was afraid of that - I had only 2 devices to test it on and a large number of others have come out since his code even.  If you open the project the VB test app will run the C# code in the LIB prj.  When it errors, you could tell me the line and actual exception and I'll see if I can goggle a fix.  Need more info though like when it happens, where, what etc.

Comment: I'm just grateful for what you've done so far. So I plugged in the Galaxy S3 and it has two storage areas ("Internal storage" and "SD card"). When I run the C# code I get an error at line 107 `this._device.Content(out content);` "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". `content` is NULL but there is a `DeviceID` set.

Comment: I *suspect* the deal is that the "Internal storage" and "SD card" things are Devices within your Device (nested).  So, as with IsFile, IsFolder it might need an IsDevice.  You could change the VB code to NOT poll that device based on the name and see if it also crashed on both of them.

Comment: There is only one device connected and the FriendlyName appears to be `""`. It fails when it tries to get the content. My (uneducated) guess is that each one is a device within a device. [edit] just spotted your comment :)

Comment: If I stick `if (device.FriendlyName.Equals("\"\""))` around the `getContents` call and `foreach` then it executes fine but displays nothing. Looks like there is only one device.

Comment: I looked at that other WPD project and while it is more extensive, the chewy center is nearly identical to Geers blog. I am not sure this API is meant to be used with that device though. I think it is intended for less intelligent devices like a eBook reader, camera etc.  When connected, you could try to use "Open as Portable Device" from Explorer (right click) on either the device or internal storage items.

Comment: Unfortunately when I right-click the device there is no "Open as Portable Device" option (presumably because it's already a portable device). Right-clicking on the storage items just shows open, open in new window and properties menu items.

Comment: As I said, I am not sure that API is meant for a device like a Tablet which has an OS to manage things.  It appears to be a means to allow Windows to do things like get content type (GIF, MP3, AVI...etc) transfer etc on a device with limited smarts.

Answer (score 1):

(this should be a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26660243/12154974), but I don't have enough reputation to add comments)

@Richard said:

> When I run the C# code I get an error at line 107 this._device.Content(out content); "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

Adding the line:

```
this.Connect();
```

before line 107 solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

This [MediaDevices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediaDevices/) nuget package should suit you.

From package description:

> API to communicate with MTP / WPD devices like smart phones, tablets
>   and cameras. Documentation included.

([GitHub link](https://github.com/Bassman2/MediaDevices)).

To open a device and write a file on it:

```
var devices = MediaDevice.GetDevices();
using (var device = devices.First(d => d.FriendlyName == "My Cell Phone"))
{
  device.Connect();

  device.CreateDirectory(@"\Phone\Documents\Temp");

  using(FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(@"C:/Temp/Test.txt"))
  {
    device.UploadFile(stream, @"\Phone\Documents\Temp\Test.txt");
  }
  device.Disconnect();
}
```