# how to detect android's device name in Windows?

Tags: android, vb.net, mtp

How can i detect android's device name when there is an android device connected to Windows?

[image]

Comment: Found the solution....

[Accessing an MTP device in Visual Basic .NET][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26514869/accessing-an-mtp-device-in-visual-basic-net